# The number of ways to distribute balls between boxes

Tags: combinatorics

By how many ways can we distribute 5 balls between 3 different boxes if

1) the balls are identical

2) the balls are different

My attempt:-

1) the number of ways = $C^{5+3-1}_3$ = 36

2) the number of ways = $P^5_3 =60$

Are these answers correct ?

Comment: If the balls are different then we get to choose one of the three for each of the five balls, hence $3^5$.  The other answer is wrong as well...just count it by hand rather than rely on a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) applying stars and bars we find $\binom{5+3-1}{3-1}=\binom72=21$ possibilities.

2) For each of the $5$ balls there are $3$ choices, so there are $3^5$ possibilities.